# Connection Issues with Java program using oracle 11g

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

I am having connection issues with my java program interacting with oracle 11g using `ojdbc7.jar`. I am using jdk 1.8 on windows 7 platform. I'm getting an error with the connection.

I'm writing my whole program below:

```
package mydao;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class AdminDAO {
    Connection con;
    public void connectionMethod() {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:oracleEE", "system", "tiger");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            cnfe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void loginCheck(String uid, String pwd) {
        connectionMethod();
        try {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM ADMIN_LOGIN WHERE ADMINUID=? AND ADMINPWD=?";
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, uid);
            ps.setString(2, pwd);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                rs.getString(1);
                rs.getString(2);
                rs.getString(3);
            }
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AdminDAO a = new AdminDAO();
        a.loginCheck("avi", "avi3");
    }
}
```

But I'm getting error like this:

```
    run:
    java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:673)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:715)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:385)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:30)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:564)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at mydao.AdminDAO.connectionMethod(AdminDAO.java:33)
    at mydao.AdminDAO.loginCheck(AdminDAO.java:43)
    at mydao.AdminDAO.main(AdminDAO.java:74)

    Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:445)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:464)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:594)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:229)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1360)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:486)
    ... 9 more

    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:162)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:133)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:411)
    ... 14 more

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mydao.AdminDAO.loginCheck(AdminDAO.java:61)
    at mydao.AdminDAO.main(AdminDAO.java:74)
    Java Result: 1
```

Can anyone help me getting out of this problem? I'm confused how to recover from this error.

Comment: Is your oracle listener up and running, and is your database mounted?

Comment: I am using the same code to execute using mysql server and it's working properly. I am accessing the same result in sql plus cmd prompt, but not via a java program.

Comment: what´s the ouput of the command lsnrctl status ?

Comment: Can anyone help me in getting out of this error?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. @rafalopez79

Comment: what´s the output if you run from a cmd window the command: "lsnrctl status".

Comment: C:\Users\Avinash>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.1.0.6.0 - Production on 08-OCT-2014 00:41:19

Copyright (c) 1991, 2007, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   32-bit Windows Error: 2: No such file or directory
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=Dell-XPS)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   32-bit Windows Error: 61: Unknown err

Comment: try starting the listener with: "lsnrctl start"

Comment: C:\Users\Avinash>lsnrctl start

LSNRCTL for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.1.0.6.0 - Production on 08-OCT-2014 00:48:14

Copyright (c) 1991, 2007, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting tnslsnr: please wait...

TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
 TNS-00530: Protocol adapter error

Comment: And if you start the TNS-Listener service from windows services form?? services.msc

Comment: I got that. Thank you so much ^_^

Comment: I will put the official answer below ...

Comment: Should it not be `/oracleEE` with a slash?

Comment: And why do you think so?

Comment: but, finally, it works??

Answer (score 0):

Please try to start the TNS-Listener service in services.msc.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the server is not listening on the specified port or hostname.

Check if your service is running and if so check the port on which it is listening. If your oracle service is listening in different port update the same in your code and check.